# lacie drive click and beep

Tags: hard-drive

I have a usb lacie drive (1tb) which for some reason is doing a click and beep about every second and will not be recognised at all.

Any ideas as to why this might be occuring? I really need to get the data off this drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a USB-powered 2.5" drive, try a different USB port. I have an oldish Seagate that makes a beeping noise if it doesn't get enough power from the USB port.

Comment: Its a powered drive. So it has a separate power cable.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is really important, I'd disassemble the enclosure.  Inside is certainly a standard hard drive which you can disconnect from the internal electronics and connect to a PC using standard means.

If you continue to have issues then the issue is with the drive itself and not the enclosure electronics.

If connecting the drive to PC lets you get data off if it, I'd look at the circuit board for any part numbers and search Ebay or other auction sites for a replacement, or replace the enclosure.

Also: make sure you are using the correct AC adapter for the drive and that there are no issues with that adapter.  If you are using one of those "universal" AC adapters with switchable tips make sure the tip is positive or negative as the drive requires and that the adapter is at the right voltage.